# Wrong numeric properties round in the Autodesk viewer , B360 viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I use standard [Autodesk viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/). When I open the model in the Forge viewer and choose some object I received 
[Autodesk model viewer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aVAZ.png)

but numeric properties is wrong. 
For example, it shows that "Versatz unten"  3.92600000000001 m
But if I GET this property from the model using your API it will be "3.926 m"

I tried the same model on B360 viewer and rounding of properties is even worse 
For example, it shows that "Versatz unten"  4 m
But if I GET this property from the model using your API it will be "3.926 m" [B360 model viewer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdY4g.png)

This problem affects on filter method we use in our project
Is there some solution to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Which viewer version are you using? Would you mind testing it on A360 personal to check if this issue also comes out?

https://a360.autodesk.com/

Comment: @EasonKang I use standard [Autodesk viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/) . I tested the same model on A360 viewer and rounding is even worse. "Versatz unten" - 4 m, other properties where was 0,46399999999 on A360 shows as 0 m

I will add this information to the main question

Comment: Could you provide a small model without confidential data to ‘forge.help@auotdesk.com’? Let,s what happened to your model

Comment: @EasonKang Unfortunately this model is the industrial secret. I will try to find some other model with the same problem. Maybe information that it is a Revit model will be helpful for you